# OpenSSL::PKCS7.sign with a specific date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-signature, origami

I'm using origami to digitaly sign a pdf.

Is it possible to use OpenSSL::PKCS7.sign to sign a pdf and pass as a parameter or as an attribute an specific date to be the date of signing?

If not is there any way of accomplishing this?

I have been searching but found nothing on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want makes no sense from security point of view. You are actually asking "how do I spoof signing time in my documents". Well, you can't do this without capturing control over one of authorized TSA (timestamping authorities) in one way or another.

Update: In general it's possible to put any time to PDF signature as one of its attributes. As I look into Origami's source code, I don't see any way to put time to the signature.

Comment: Maybe the OP only wants to manually set the signing time attribute?

Comment: Ok you'r right but I needed to cgeck if it was possible, thanks

Should I mark this as accepted?